# Delphi Seattle changing IDE default folder settings

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying, so far with no success, to change the default directory
where the Seattle IDE prompts to save a newly-created VCL project
and its units.  Under

`Tools | Options | Environment variables | System variables`

there are a number of environment variables which begin with BDS,
e.g. BDSProjectsDir & BDSUserDir which all point to various places
under C:\Users.

My question is: where do these default values come from?  Although
they appear under "System variables" (which to me suggests the OS System 
variables), they are not present in my OS System variables (nor the OS User
Environment variables).  I've searched the entire OS Registry and none 
of them is found there, either.

I've tried adding User Overrides of them to the IDE Tools | Options
pop-up, but these overrides are ignored when I create a new project
and the Save dialog defaults to the directory under the "System variables" 
instead, which I specifically do **NOT* want, because where I save my 
Delphi files isn't even on drive C: and it is a pain to have to
navigate to it every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These variables are set from the IDE and promoted to the build system. You can call *rsvars.bat* from the bin folder to have these set in your environment.

BTW, the folder for new projects is set in *Environment Options - Default project*.
[image]